# How to close file opened via file readable in Tcl

Tags: tcl

When the input file is corrupt, the input file is held open by my code and I am unable to delete it. To delete it, I might close the command line which ran my code so the file is closed automatically then I am able to delete.

But what is the command to close a file opened via [file readable?](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/file+readable)

Comment: Trivial inspection of that code indicates that it ought to be closing the channel already.

Comment: I keep re-reading the question, but I fail to see what it is after. Can you pls. show a snippet of code? `file readable` does not open a file?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I think you could use something like this:

```
proc close_all_files {} {
    foreach channel [file channels "file*"] {
        close $channel
    }
}
```

Then call close_all_files when you need to close files that have been previously opened.

Warning: this will close absolutely all files opened within the script. There are not a lot of options if you don't know the file identifier that was created by `file readable`, unless you modify that `proc` to add the file identifier to an accessible list outside the proc, the easiest example being to use a global list:

```
proc file'readable name {
    global filesIds
    set rc [catch {open $name} fp]
    if {[string match "file*" $fp]} {
        lappend filesIds $fp
    }
    if {$rc==0} {close $fp}
    expr {$rc==0}
}
```

And then if you know the file order for which you used `file readable`, you can pick which one you need to close.